# How to fix "ActionSheet of UIAlertController has the conflict constraint" error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My code runs successfully on iOS12.1, but recently when I update the version of iOS, Xcode, macOS to iOS12.2 Xcode10.2 and macOS10.14.4, there is something wrong in my project.
There is no problem with my app interface, but when I open the action sheet, it tells me that my constraints are conflicting.
How can I solve it?
[this is my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faTPw.jpg)
[this is the warning in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/debec.jpg)

I reset the constraints of the interface, but no matter how I get it, I still have the same problem.

Those are my codes, once I tap the button, the action sheet occurred, and Xcode tells me that my constraints are conflicting

```swift
@IBAction func newToDoBarButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "New or Edit", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let newToDoAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "New Item", style: .default, handler: {(_) in
            let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let registerVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewToDoStoryboard") as! ToDoViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(registerVC, animated: true)
        })

        let editInformationOfListAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit Information", style: .default, handler: {(_) in
            let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let registerVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditStoryboard") as! EditItemTableViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(registerVC, animated: true)
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(newToDoAlertAction)
        alertController.addAction(editInformationOfListAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alertController,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }
```

I except there is no warning of the conflicting constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to manually silent the constraint alert.

```
   @IBAction func newToDoBarButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
     ...
    self.present(alertController,animated: true,completion: nil)

   alertController.view.subviews.flatMap({$0.constraints}).filter{ (one: NSLayoutConstraint)-> (Bool)  in
      return (one.constant < 0) && (one.secondItem == nil) &&  (one.firstAttribute == .width)
   }.first?.isActive = false

  }
```

Comment: Which problem did your code fix? I don’t know the meaning of your code, could you please tell me?

Comment: You may not need to know the warning issue，it’s a big

Comment: you said it is a bug？